# Differentiate between a scroll caused by .scrollLeft and a user trying to scroll in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a scrollbar that has to follow some timeline. It is being constantly scrolled with `.scrollLeft` using `setInterval`.

I still want the user to be able to naturally take control and just drag the scrollbar away. If I can detect the user did that, I would just turn off the `setInterval` timer and leave the control to the user until he explicitly turns the auto scroll back on.

Is there a way to differentiate the user scroll event, from the scroll created by `.scrollLeft`?

Answer (score 3):

You can set a flag before changing `scrollLeft` and clear it afterwards, then check the flag in the `scroll` event.
Since Javascript is run on the UI thread, it is not possible for the user to scroll while your code is running.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to give up using a scroll-bar at all and do it using CSS and a [jQuery slider control](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-jquery-slider-to-scroll-a-div). This also gives you the option of making it look more like a time-line. you can set the scroller elements to whatever CSS you want.

There are a few out there, but it's not too hard to roll-your-own using a [jQuery draggable control](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and constraining one axis inside a long, narrow container DIV.